# jQuery css call back function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I'm trying to expand my searchbar using jQuery.
Also I want to hide the nav links.

I have some jQuery code like this. This code works fine when focus.

```
$(".searchBox input").focus(function(){
    $("#navlinks").css('display','none');
   $(this).css({'width':'200px','-moz-transition':'width 0.5s ease-out','-webkit-transition':'width 0.5s ease-out','transition':'width 0.5s ease-out'});
});

 $(".searchBox input").focus(function(){
       $(this).css({'width':'100px','-moz-transition':'width 0.5s ease-out','-webkit-transition':'width 0.5s ease-out','transition':'width 0.5s ease-out'});
$("#navlinks").css('display','block');
    });
```

The second function also works fine `except it display the content before animation complete.`

So I want `$("#navlinks").css('display','block');` to be exectuted only when animate complete.

Can anyone tell me how?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you know how long takes your animations, why do not use setTimeout() after CSS change?
As far as I see your animation takes about 0.5 seconds. You could easily execute your "callback" seamlessly at end of your animation specifying the same amount of time in milliseconds.

```
 $(".searchBox input").focus(function(){
       $(this).css({'width':'100px','-moz-transition':'width 0.5s ease-out','-webkit-transition':'width 0.5s ease-out','transition':'width 0.5s ease-out'});
       setTimeout( function() {
            $("#navlinks").css('display','block');
       }, 500);
  });
```

Answer (score 16):

.css() doesn't have a callback function, but .animate() does. Just set the time to 0 and use animate.

```
$(".searchBox input").on('focus',function(){
   $(this).animate({width:100,mozTransition:'width 500ms ease-out',webkitTransition:'width 500ms ease-out',transition:'width 500ms ease-out'},0,function(){
       $("#navlinks")
            .delay(500)
            .css({display:'block'});
   });
});
```

Edit: included delay, which is required. (Thanks eicto)

Comment: Totally wrong.  jQuery will not wait (or even know about) for the CSS animation.

Comment: than use animate without transition

Comment: @eicto: That's slower, especially on mobile

Comment: use delay() than with time of css  animation

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `.animate()` like

```
$(".searchBox input").focus(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        'width': '100px'       
    }, 500, function() {
        $("#navlinks").css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

This will work on all browsers, and the navlinks command will be insured to begin after the animation is complete. Note: the `500` is the number of milliseconds the animation will take to complete, so you can adjust accordingly.

Here is the `.animate()` documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

I came along here, but I used another solution:

```
$('.something').one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
    function(event) {
        // Do something when the transition ends

 });
```

As you see, this is doing something, when the transition has ended.

This is described here:
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end

Greetings,
Lars

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition) is described 
`transitionend` event, let's try that:

CSS:

```
#test {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition all 1s;
    transition all 1s;
}
#test.wide {
    width: 200px;

}
```

JS:

```
var test = $('#test');
 test.bind('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () {
        $('body').append('<div>END!</div>');
    })
$('button').click(function () {
    test.toggleClass('wide');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/nUVU8/)

Comment: I tried your sample on my iPad but it did not work at all... :(

Comment: Transition works. But it did not appear the div at end of animation. May be try to specify a different element instead of "body"

Comment: you can try, as i told, it works for me and I have no iPad to check.

Comment: No way. I have tried modifying your sample (http://jsfiddle.net/nUVU8/4/) but it continue to not catch the event transitionend. I'll double check your link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23533/discussion-between-eicto-and-freedev)

Comment: I don't know if it is jsfiddler. May be it is. Because I have changed the code following your suggestion and again. The alert did not appear. http://jsfiddle.net/nUVU8/7/

Comment: I added 
oTransitionEnd and webkitTransitionEnd as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility)